# jquery form plugin / rails file upload / plain text respond instead of html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

i'm trying to get a file upload via ajax form to work.. as i am using the jquery form plugin the file upload works well.. but the rendered html in the respond_to js block is returned as plain text. hope someone can help

controller:

`if @visitreport.save

    flash[:notice] = "Der Besuchsbericht wurde erstellt."

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html{redirect_to @visitreport}

      format.js

    end`

create.js.erb:

`$("#last_customers").replaceWith('<div id="last_customers"><%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'customers/last_customers') %> </div>');

    $("#reminder").replaceWith('<div id="reminder"><%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "customers/reminder",  :locals => {:date => Date.today+1}) %>');`
.. and some other jquery - magic

_last_customers.html.haml: -- just for example

`%h5 Die zuletzt bearbeiteten Kunden

%hr

.subcolumns

  -get_user_customers.each do |uc|

    .c25l

      .subcl

        =link_to("#{uc.id}", customer_path(uc.id))

    .c75l

      .subcl

        =link_to("#{get_customer_name(uc.id)}", customer_path(uc.id))`

the response looks like this:

`&lt;div class="report round_corners box_shadow"&gt;&lt;h5&gt;bearbeitet am Freitag, 04. Juni 2010, 12:06 Uhr&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;div class='text-right'&gt;   per Telefon   am 05.07.2010 &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p class='report_content'&gt;   fg &lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class='text-right reminder'&gt;   Wiedervorlage am 14.12.2015   &lt;br /&gt;   &lt;a href="/visitreports/138/edit"&gt;Bericht bearbeiten &gt;&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;h5&gt;Dateien&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;a href="/assets/27"&gt;bg_mainmenu.gif&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt;`

application.js:

```
("#new_visitreport").submit(function() {
$(this).ajaxSubmit(
dataType  : 'script',
  iframe    : true,
success   : function (data) {
    data = eval(data.replace("<pre>", "").replace("</pre>", ""));
  }
});
return false;
});
```

what am i doing wrong?
hope somebody can help!
jquery version 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery Form [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload), it is recommended to wrap the response in `textarea`. Example in erb:

```
<textarea>
  jQuery("#documents").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render @document) %>");
</textarea>
```

Then set the content type to `text/html` on your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  # jQuery Form needs to have text/html as Content-Type.
  format.js { render :content_type => Mime::HTML.to_s }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works quite well for me .. It seems i've overlooked the the textarea part in the jquery form doc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) explains it. It has to do with the hidden iframe technique used to upload the file. The server response is written to the hidden iframe. It's fine if the response is HTML or XML, not if it's JavaScript or JSON because some characters will then have to be represented in entity codes. So as a workaround, the JavaScript and JSON codes can be wrapped in textarea.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand that. However, `text/plain` wouldn't have any problems with this. Anyway, I read that IE sometimes inspects the contents for text/plain contents and thus it won't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Must be the late night drowsiness :)

I tested with `text/plain`, but it doesn't work at least with Firefox 5. It says `syntax error &lt;textarea&gt;`. Removing the textarea tag gives different kind of errors, as if the JS is not properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 3 and you'd like to simplify the process a bit, you should try out the Remotipart gem:

http://rubygems.org/gems/remotipart

http://github.com/leppert/remotipart